# How to multiply integers in list with constant and overwrite list value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, integer

I have a very basic problem. How can I multiply integers within a list with a constant? If the integer in the list passes a logical test, I want it's value to be multiplied by a constant. The problem is that when I print the list afterwards, the integers have not changed. Many thanks in advance.

```
x = [10,25,66]

def multiply(list):
    for i in list:
        if i%5==0:
            i = i*2
            print i 

multiply(x)
print x
```

Comment: consider numpy for such case, where you can directly multiply an array 'by 2'

Comment: You never assign your changes anywhere... (`i = i*2`)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension to do this

```
>>> x = [10,25,66]
>>> x = [i*2 if i%5==0 else i for i in x]
>>> x
[20, 50, 66]
```

Comment: The original code tries to modigy a list passed to a function in place.  This code creates a new list instead.  (Not necessarily a problem, but a noteworthy difference.)

Answer (score 1):

well you are multiplying the item itself and not assigning to the list.

This will do it

```
x = [10,25,66]

def multiply(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i]%5==0:
            list[i] = list[i] * 2

multiply(x)
print x
```

So what I changed is that now you are getting the indexes in the for loop. Then checking the condition and after that you are **assigning the new value back to the list**, this is the thing that makes the change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the same list by iterating through your list with `enumerate` and modifying indices that match your condition:

```
x = [10,25,66]

def multiply(lst):
    for index, value in enumerate(lst):
        if value % 5 == 0:
            lst[index] = value * 2
            print lst[index]

multiply(x)
print x
# [20, 50, 66]
```

Comment: Better than range would be using an enumerate

Comment: @Keatinge Thanks for noting. Looks better

Answer (score 0):

numpy solution:

```
In [56]: x = np.array([10,25,66])

In [57]: x[x % 5 == 0] *= 2  # solution from @Sven Marnach

In [58]: x
Out[58]: array([20, 50, 66])
```

Comment: An even more concise solution to modify the array in place instead of creating a new one is `x[x % 5 == 0] *= 2`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes, indeed, thank you! It's much better and faster solution!